# Software to develop a chatbot that uses data from Elasticsearch

Tags: chat, framework

I'm currently taking a look at chatbot development. The plan is to have a chatbot on our website that can answer questions. We also want to see if its possible to have a chatbot which can send a query to other softwares to get an result. For example we have a search engine created with Elasticsearch. We would like our chatbot to be able to send a query to Elasticsearch, recieve the results from the query, and then give the user a clear answer from that result.

Is there any software, framework, or other services that can be used to create a chatbot with these functions? I've taken a look at Google's Dialogflow but I don't know if it can do these functions. If it can then we would probably be fine with using it.

Comment: https://discuss.api.ai/t/how-do-i-use-api-ai-to-get-data-from-external-applications-and-use-it-in-the-bots-reponse/11112/4

Comment: Would a normal Elasticsearch search widget be enough, if it is made to visually look like a chat widget and only return one or a couple results rather than pages of results? If not, please detail what other features you would need, thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I don't think that would be enough. I would imagine the chatbot will have a dialogue flow/tree it'll follow to understand precisely what the user wants to know. The user might have a question that could be multiple results so the chatbot will ask questions to narrow down the results (e.g listing multiple possibilities and asking if they meant one of those and if thats the case which one they meant). The chatbot doesn't have to be able to provide results for all questions but could be able to guide the user to find it themself (by using the search engine or calling an advisor).

Comment: It seems like this process of "asking and narrowing down" will depend on the structure of your Elasticsearch data. Are you ready to code, or do you require a tool that "auto-discovers" the data structure (not sure whether that is possible)?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I'm prepared to work with code if its neccecary. Obviously if there are tools that can do the job properly I would consider using them but either way is fine.